# Change User Password at Next Login With a VBScript

Tags: vbscript, adsi

I have a standalone computer connected to a basic router at home and has time warner. I am trying to write a script so that i can run it on the computer and it will make me change my password at next login. 
Ive tried the following script where UAL-10167 is the computer name and the username is: UAL-Lab-Tech 
And it is not working. Any Advise would be great!!

```
strComputer = "UAL-10167"  
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/UAL-Lab-Tech")  
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1  
objUser.SetInfo
```

Comment: Can you give more information about how it is failing?

Comment: Line: 2  Char:2  Error: The network path was not found.  Code: 80070035  Source: (null)

Comment: I checked to make sure the names were correct also.

Comment: I mean i can go into lusrmgr.msc and change it, but i would like a script to be able to.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but it still unanswered...

To force a user to set his or her password on the next log on set the `pwdLastSet` property to `0`, as in...

```
objUser.Put "pwdLastSet", 0
objUser.SetInfo
```